# How detect a input injected from bash in a background process using std::in and getline()

Tags: c++, bash, sh, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I have a binary compiled in Cpp with the following code:

```
std::string input;
getline(std::cin, input);
std::cout << "Message given: " << input << std::endl;
```

If I execute this example, and write in the terminal "Hello world!" works perfectly:

```
Message given: Hello world!
```

Now, I launch the executable in redirecting stdout:

```
./basicsample >> output/test
```

If I try to inject inputs using file descriptor:

```
echo "Hello world!" > /proc/${PID}/fd/0
```

The message appear in terminal that launched the process:

```
[vgonisanz@foovar bash]$ ./basicsample >> output/test
Hello world!
```

But the message no appear in the programs output. I expect to get the message processed by getline, and it is not detected! But, If I write directly in that bash, the program get the input. I'm trying to do a script to inject inputs in a background process but it is not working.

How could I inject inputs to be detected into the process without do it manually?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that using expect, this could work, but I will prefer to avoid dependencies like this. After several tries, the best way to do it without dependencies is to use a pipe, in example:

```
mkdir tmp; mkfifo tmp/input.pipe; nohup ./basicsample  tmp/user.out 2> tmp/nohup.err
```

This will run the creating a input pipe, an output for console and error.
Then, just feed the pipe using:

```
echo "Hello world!" > tmp/input.pipe
```

The problem of this is, the pipe works only once. After getting an input, it won't never listen it again. Maybe this is the way but I don't know how to avoid to lost the focus.

I tried to redirect it using several ways like files, etc, but it doesn't works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `$PID` the process id of `basicsample`, or the shell? The point of output redirection is that `basicsample` no longer uses the same standard output as the shell that called it.

Comment: Writing to the shell's standard output is not at all the same as writing to its standard input, which is what `basicsample` is reading from, even if the shell is using the same terminal device for both.

Comment: Yes, $PID is the ID. And yes, I'm trying to send the input from another terminal. Anyway, the problem is I cannot send the data. If a use a pipe, after sending something with echo, the program never listen again... And I will like to avoid using dependencies like sexpect and expect.

Comment: Does writing to `/proc/<pid of basicsample>/fd/1` do what you want?

Comment: Nope, I want to send output to a file, and get input from a pipe several times, not only once. The point is, run interactive program from a bash script if the process is in the background, exporting the whole output to a file during execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it without dependencies is to use a pipe, in example:

```sh
mkdir tmp
mkfifo tmp/input.pipe
(tail -f tmp/input.pipe) | ./basicsample > tmp/log.0 &
```

This will run creating an input pipe and an output saved in log file. You can prevent console blocking using the operator `&` to launch it in background.

Then inject data using:

```sh
echo "YOUR_STRING" > tmp/input.pipe
```

It should work for your posed problem.